# Select conditionally bound columns from 2 tables into one line

Tags: sql, postgresql

I searched, but seems I haven't found the right keyword for describing what I am trying to achieve, so please be lenient if this is a known problem, just point me to the right keywords.

I have following tables/entries:

```
select * from personnes where id=66;

id | aclid | referendid |     login      | validated |    passwd                            
66 |       |            | toto@tiiti.com | f         | $2y$10$w3DRh/g2Tebu/mkMcQz32OUB.dDjFiBP99vWlMrrPWpR45JZDdw4W
```

and

```
 select * from pattributs where (name='nom' OR name='prenom') AND persid=66;

 id |  name  | value | persid 
----+--------+-------+--------
 90 | prenom | Jean  |     66
 91 | nom    | Meyer |     66
```

Now I use that form for not cluttering the main table, since depending on the case, I record the name, or not....

but having a view as a table of the completed table would be nice, so I tried:

```
select (personnes."id","login",
    (select "value" from pattributs where "name"='nom' AND "persid"=66),
    (select "value" from pattributs where "name"='prenom' AND "persid"=66)
    ) from personnes where personnes.id=66;
```

which seems to do the job:

```
             row               
--------------------------------
 (66,toto@tiiti.com,Meyer,Jean)
```

but the column tags disappeared, and being able to fetch them from the invoking php script is immensely useful, but when I add:

```
 select (personnes."id","login",
          (select "value" from pattributs where "name"='nom' AND "persid"=66),
         (select "value" from pattributs where "name"='prenom' AND "persid"=66) as 'prenom') 
   from personnes where personnes.id=66;
```

I get a syntax error at the as directive... So probably I haven't understood how to do this properly, the braces indicate that this isn't anymore in tabular form), so how can I achieve the following result:

```
id | login         | nom   | prenom
66 |toto@tiiti.com | Meyer | Jean
```

The idea being to store a suitable view for each use case, bundling only the relevant columns.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question: You are loosing the column names because you are creating a simple data set, a row. This is done by your braces. Without them you should get your expected result.

---

But your solution is not very well: You should avoid to calculate your single columns in every single subquery. This could be done easily in one `SELECT`:

```
select
    pe.id,
    pe.login,
    MIN(pa.value) FILTER (WHERE pa.name = 'nom') as nom,
    MIN(pa.value) FILTER (WHERE pa.name = 'prenom') as prenom
from 
    personnes pe
join pattributs pa ON pe.id = pa.persid AND pe.id = 66
where pa.name = 'nom' or pa.name = 'prenom'
group by pe.id, pe.login
```

First you'll need a `JOIN` to get the right datasets of both tables together. You should join on the `id`.

Then you have the problem that you have two rows for the name (which seems not very well designed, why not two columns?). These two values can be grouped by the `id`. Now you could aggregate them.

What I am doing is to "aggregate" them (it doesn't matter what function I am using because it should be only one value). The `FILTER` clause filters out the right value.

Comment: wow :D now i am definitely outside my comfort zone :D, the reason why serveral lines for name is that i have usecases, where there is no name at all, and others where a lot of other fields make a record.... unfortunately your request returns 0 hits? and i definitely don't underrstand the MIN(value), the fields are text fields?

Comment: impressive, i replaced pe.id = pa.id agains =pa.persid, and it works!! well now it will take time understand what happens here...

Comment: @NohKumado Concerning MIN(). We have two rows: One with nom and one with prenom. To get them into one resulting row we need to aggregate them with GROUP. Now we have both values to work with. Maybe we could put it into one array with the function array_agg(values). This would result into {'jean', 'meyer'}. Now we want only one of these. That's what the filter does: It filters the value where the name is 'nom' or 'prenom' (do it twice for every kind of name). This would result in {'jean'} or {'meyer'}... (1/2)

Comment: But we don't need an array but a single value. So we don't need an array_agg function but another one. Since we have only one value (because of the filter we only have 'jean' or 'meyer') it doesn't matter what aggregate function we are using. MIN of a text column gives you the smallest text in that column (alphabetical order). So the smallest text in a set of exactly one value is that value. So I simply used MIN because of the GROUP I needed to use a function. I could have used MAX as well or whatever a function that gives me one text out of the set. Is that clear to you?

Comment: heh never thought of using those functions that way, but yes, that makes it clearer! thanks a lot! BTW you should probably correct the join condition?

Comment: Yes, I did it :)